# Make Kubernetes wait for Pod termination before removing from Service endpoints

Tags: kubernetes

According to [Termination of Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination), step 7 occurs simultaneously with 3. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening and have 7 occur only *after* the `Pod`'s graceful termination (or expiration of the grace period)?

The reason why I need this is that my `Pod`'s termination routine requires `my-service-X.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` to resolve to the `Pod`'s IP during the whole process, but the corresponding `Endpoint` gets removed as soon as I run `kubectl delete` on the `Pod` / `Deployment`.

*Note:* In case it helps making this clear, I'm running a bunch of clustered VerneMQ (Erlang) nodes which, on termination, dump their contents to other nodes on the cluster — hence the need for the nodenames to resolve correctly during the whole termination process. Only then should the corresponding `Endpoint`s be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately kubernetes was designed to remove the Pod from the endpoints at the same time as the prestop hook is started (see link in question to [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination)):

> At the same time as the kubelet is starting graceful shutdown, the
> control plane removes that shutting-down Pod from Endpoints

This [google kubernetes docs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace) says it even more clearly:

> 1. Pod is set to the “Terminating” State and removed from the
>    endpoints list of all Services

There also was also a [feature request for that.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/88085) which was not recognized.

**Solution for helm users**

But if you are using helm, you can use [***hooks***](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) (e.g. pre-delete,pre-upgrade,pre-rollback). Unfortunately this helm hook is an extra pod which can not access all pod resources.

This is an example for a *hook*:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: graceful-shutdown-hook
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-delete,pre-upgrade,pre-rollback
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: graceful-shutdown-hook
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: graceful-shutdown
          image: busybox:1.28.2
          command: ['sh', '-cx', '/bin/sleep 15']
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 0
```

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work for pod scale-down case

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider using [headless service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#headless-services) instead of using ClusterIP one. That way your apps will discover using the actual endpoint IPs and the removal from endpoint list will not break the availability during shutdown, but will remove from discovery (or from ie. ingress controller backends in nginx contrib)

Comment: I'm already using a headless service. However, I need to keep discovery due to the way Erlang clustering works.